# name of the maths function that gives one if two inputs are similar

Tags: functions

What is the name of this function? ${\delta\left(y_j,c_k\right) = 1}$ if ${y_j = c_k}$, ${0}$ otherwise.?

Comment: *similar* is not the same as *equal*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is quite similar to [Kronecker's delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta).